# Error mounting in Ubuntu and Unmountable boot volume in Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, windows-10

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 as dual boot for some time now. Everyday I'm using both Ubuntu for dev purposes and Windows for some other stuff. Sometimes I'm getting the error `Error mounting device` on Ubuntu when I'm trying to get into a partition. When that happens I run the `sudo ntfsfix dev/sdaxx` command and that fixes it.

Now when I tried moving to Windows from Ubuntu I'm getting a **blue screen** saying **UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME** and I can't get into Windows. Is there any way I can fix that error in Ubuntu? Because it says to fix that I have to get into Windows from a Windows bootable drive(USB). Is there any other way?

P.S: After getting the error in Windows, when I log into Ubuntu the same C partition throws `Error mounting device`. Other partitions are working fine. After I run `ntfsfix` on the C partition I can access it as well.

What have I done wrong? I just need to get into Windows.

[image: This is the error I'm getting.]

Comment: You've done most things wrong, starting with accessing the Windows system partition from other OS. Always use a shared NTFS data only partition. Then you *forgot* to disable fast boot in Windows, the reason for the errors, and finally you used tools in Ubuntu to correct NTFS partitions where only Windows tools should be used. Now, how can we help you?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/792863/install-ubuntu-on-seperate-hard-drive#comment1193198_792863

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. don't run ntfsfix... it's only a last resort... and it has consequences.
2. fix your Windows to work in a dual-boot environment...

**In Windows...**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

And lastly...

3. as @MichaelBay suggests... create a new NTFS partition to share files between Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a good answer. FWIW, I generally refer people to [this post](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [this one](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) on a Windows forum for information on disabling Fast Startup and Hibernate, respectively, in Windows. (In my experience, it's necessary to disable both those features to really fix the problem.)

Comment: As heynnema mentioned I've unchecked the checkbox "Turn On fast Startup" (before) , and have disabled secure boot in BIOS as well. 
Now using a bootable windows 10 usb, I logged into windows. But I can't understand what have I done wrong (except accessing files on C partition when I'm on Ubuntu)

Anyway Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema, how to share files in a NTFS partition. As an example how can I access same eclipse workplace in both Ubuntu and Windows. I haved moved all my projects to D:/ partition and I can access it them in Ubuntu as well. But the thing is if I was working on them in ubuntu and moved in to windows and came back to ubuntu, I have to re-open the projects again in eclipse as the path is not showing. How can I solve this using shared NTFS partition ?

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana have you added the D: shared NTFS partition to your /etc/fstab so that it auto-mounts in Ubuntu?